# How to embed portlets correctly to a Liferay 7 theme template?

Tags: liferay, freemarker, portlet, liferay-theme, liferay-7

The blank theme Yeomann generates, has a basic `<@liferay.breadcrumb/>` tag, and I could even see `<@liferay.dockbar/>` in some Freemarker template files...

Since I couldn't find any ***documentation*** regarding these tags, let's call them "shorthands".

**Question 1.:** Where can someone find **a list / library** of all usable "shorthands" which enable the easiest way of embedding portlets to templates?

I know, there is the possibility to write something like this for embedding a Web Content Display:

```
<@liferay_portlet["runtime"]
    defaultPreferences="${freeMarkerPortletPreferences}"
    portletProviderAction=portletProviderAction.VIEW
    instanceId="uniquename1"
portletName="com_liferay_journal_content_web_portlet_JournalContentPortlet" />
```

It's just huge, and ***there is no documentation*** about which property means what, how this functions under the hood, and where can one find other implemented **portlet class names** (**Portlet ID**s if you wish).

**Question 2-3.:** Since I might be wrong, could someone please link a **detailed documentation (other than [this one](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/embedding-portlets-in-themes-and-layout-templates) because there's no explanation)/forum entry** and/or a list of all the portlet class names so people shouldn't check by adding any portlet to the content of the page and verify the id from the HTML code? Could someone explain in depth how the above tag works and give an other example referring to an other portlet? Appreciations!

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: Hey Robert, you are right and I do admit that I asked for off-topic help. Besides the fact that the questions were already answered and might be useful for any newcomer to the technology mentioned, If you believe that the thread violated Stack Exchange rules, I'll delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no full documentation for your question but you can check:

What is macros and how to use them : [Here](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/freemarker-macros)

Some Freemarker Macros : [Here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/foundation/portal-template/portal-template-freemarker/src/main/resources/FTL_liferay.ftl#L45-L49)

I hope it helps

Comment: I appreciate your help! These macros can surely help me.

I'd also have an off-topic question, since I could not find any help online.
As I created my theme with Yeoman, I edited the _custom.scss, setting a color for all span tags... the problem is, that it doesn't take any effect... Any ideas?

Comment: You are welcome, u can try to add your ''css'' into **Your-theme/css/custom.css** it works for me ..
Ps : i use CSS not SASS or SCSS

Comment: Just tried, by resetting the _custom.scss to its default generated state and created a custom.css with a simple body background-color set, but no effect. Am I supposed to manage any settings? like through the template or portal app?

Comment: Just delete the _custom.scss and keep custom.css and retry, and for your 2nd question, i guess its through your template's code

Comment: Strange. Suddenly this works, but not after first deployment... Liferay surely has it's strange behaviour

Comment: Good, If gulp watch dont make any effects , try to re-deploy with gulp deloy.

Comment: second link is 404 : (

Comment: Second link has been moved to: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/apps/portal-template/portal-template-freemarker/src/main/resources/FTL_liferay.ftl